# Java Object of Type

Tags: java, object, autoboxing

I have seen this question posted a few times, but the answer does not seem to work for me.

I have an Object and need to know what type this is

ie (Object object)

when I run the code and watch object then the object.typeName is shown as `Java.lang.Long` but using `object.getClass().getName()` return as simpleType.

How do I get at the fact that the object is a Long?

Comment: Either some instanceof blocks or object.typeName.

Comment: can you show us the code you are trying?

Comment: object.getClass().getName() will give you the type Name of the reference type.

Comment: hard to tell exactly what's going on without code, but I'm guessing that your IDE is automagically typing primitives for you, whereas Java will assign a primitive long a type of simpleType.

Comment: Watch the object? Is this a debugger usage question?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I am using eclipse to build me code, and this comes with the ability to watch the object during debug. @jon Taylor The code is that I have an Object of unknown type, and I wish to find that type. As such I do not have anything more at this time.

Comment: surely you have the code you have written which for you is not working?  Please edit your question and include this code.  If you don't have any code I am not sure what you are doing.

Comment: My code is `(Object object)` <br/> the object in eclipse show object.typeName as a long.  <br/>object.getClass().getName() = simpletype.  <br/>I am looking for code that will correctly allow me to see this object as long.  <br/>btw the object type is generic so will change during each iteration.